# CSS Arrow Opacity Transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

How do I take the CSS arrows I have (see below) and make them fade in and out when you hover over each item?

**My CSS:**

```css
#menu li {
  position:relative;
}

#menu li a:after {
  content: " .";
  display: block;
  text-indent: -99em;
  border-bottom: 0.6em solid #1c525a;
  border-left: 0.6em solid transparent;
  border-right: 0.6em solid transparent;
  border-top: none;
  height: 0px;
  margin-left: -.6em;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -7px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
}
```

All the code is available [in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJ6Kg/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this I added the following:

```css
#menu li a:after {
  -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#menu li:hover a:after {
  border-bottom: 0.6em solid #1c525a;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

[See the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgPf8/) - I'm sure this code can be cleaned up or bested, but I didn't find an example/answer of this on Stack Overflow yet so I thought I would add this.